# MikTeX fails to find a font installed in Windows10 (in XeLaTeX)

Tags: xetex, miktex

I have problem using some open type fonts in Windows 10 with
XeLaTeX in MikTeX. I downloaded a Malayalam language font, "Gayathri" and tried to use it in XeLaTeX. This font is clearly listed in the Font catalague accessible from Control Panel.  The Font catalogue lists it as "Gayathri Regular".  But when I use them in XeLaTeX with the command
     \newfontfamily{\mal}[Script=Malayalam]{Gayathri Regular}
MikTeX complains it cannot find the font and starts building 'tfm's
with the following Error message.

```
  Package fontspec Error: "Gayathri Regular" cannot be found.
```

I had the same problem with many other fonts in many other languages too.

I guess it must be a  problem related to the way MikTex identifying the fonts in the operating system.
Another Malayalam language font "Kartika" that comes with Windows 10 works fine in XelaTeX.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work with lualatex? Does it work if you use the file name instead of the font name?

Comment: Windows has its own way of referencing system fonts such that it may be simply Gayathri

Comment: A workaround might be to load it by its filename, which should be in `\Windows\Fonts`.  You should also be able to get the family and full name from `otfinfo -i`.

Comment: KJO:  I simply used "Gayathri" and still MikTeX fails to find the font.

Comment: Perhaps, one should give the complete PATH to these fonts like C:\Windows\Fonts or something similar

Comment: Perhaps one shopuld give a complete PATH to these fonts like C:\Windows\Fonts

Comment: As KJO posted above, simply using "Gayathri"  instead of "Gayathri Regular" works fine. Thanks for the help.